# Splitting messages in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
tfi = '''
aardvark
albatross
alligator
alpaca
ant
anteater
antelope
'''

print(tfi)
```

Ok so, this is just a small section of the tfi string, but how do I make the code print this out in sections decided by amount of characters.

pseudo:

```
print tfi (3 chars):
returns:
    'aar'
    'dva'
```

and so on...

Comment: what's `new message`?

Comment: Examples of the output (aar first 3 chars, dva second, and so on. You need to edit to make this clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def tfi(my_string, dif):
    for i in range(0, len(my_string), dif):
        print(my_string[i:i+dif])
```

Comment: Thank you very much